# How to change file path of a variable file name?

Tags: c++, file, io, ofstream

I have found a very helpful question and answers here:
[How to create ofstream file with name of variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379390/how-to-create-ofstream-file-with-name-of-variable)

But because I have < 50 reputation on here, I cannot comment on the answer there.

I have the following code:

```
string fileName;
cout << "Enter file name: ";
cin >> fileName;
fileName += ".txt"; 
ofstream createFile;
createFile.open(fileName.c_str());
```

All I want to do is save the newly created variable name 'fileName.c_str()' to a certain path e.g /home/Data/.../fileName.c_str().

Every time I try to put the path in explicitly:

```
createFile.open("/home/Geant4/Data/.../fileName.c_str()");
```

it saves it as 'fileName.c_str()' in that particular path, without the new name. 
I can find no information online on changing paths of variable file names, so any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try: `createFile.open("/home/Geant4/Data/.../"+ filename);`

Answer (score 0):

the symboles "" means it's a string. What you did is puting code within a string, so this will be treated as a string.

You actually need to build the string that represent your file, including the path and filename.

```
string fileName;
cout << "Enter file name: ";
cin >> fileName;

string fullPath =  "/home/Geant4/Data/.../" + fileName + ".txt"; 
ofstream createFile;
createFile.open(fullPath.c_str());
```